# jQuery Select 2 - Set Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using [jQuery Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

I have a "Town Selector" on my site and am on an edit screen, Where the values that were already selected elsewhere will populate the select2 box. The problem I am having is, I am trying a foreach loop using PHP to populate it, But despite there being 2 values, It is only populating one value.

My PHP Array looks like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [town_id] => 407
            [profile_id] => 2
            [town] => Hartlepool
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [town_id] => 844
            [profile_id] => 2
            [town] => Stockton on Tees
        )

)
```

I am then looping to set the select2 values, But it is only selecting "Stockton on Tees".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#areas").select2().select2("val", null);
<?php foreach($locations as $location): ?>
$("#areas").select2().select2("val", <?php echo $location->town_id; ?>);
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I get it to select more than one on select2 loading?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your selectbox has the multiple attribute set.

Comment: Hi, How would I achieve that? select : multiple ??

Comment: I did not use select2, but you should take a look here: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: I've managed to get this to work, with adding <option selected="selected"> to the initial HTML Code.

However when changing the values, Its putting them in twice. Any ideas?